# Android: How can I customize NFC signal strength?

Tags: android, nfc

I have an app, what is communicating with a POS via NFC link. The terminal can detect the mobile phone hardly. Do I have an options to modify any NFC settings programmatically?

Comment: try to take off your case, find the sweet sport on your phone or even use a nfc antenna booster.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No. According to the Android [documentation about NFC](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/nfc/package-summary.html) there is no way today to change the output power.

Answer (score 0):

In such a use case the NFC on the phone is essentially a passive and all of the energy must be exerted from the point-of-sale. That said, positioning of the NFC tag inside the phone over the terminal matters a lot and determining exactly where the antenna is on the terminal and exactly where it is on the phone and then centering them , that will make a big difference also, if your phone has a case on it that can increase the distance between the point-of-sale terminal and the phone's internal NFC tag